# Use Heroku config vars with PHP?

Tags: php, heroku

I've been able to find information on how to use config vars in Heroku for Python, node.js, and some other languages, but not for PHP. Can you use them with PHP, or is it not supported?

[This article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) shows how to do it for Python, Java, and Ruby, but not PHP.

Comment: The PHP config var doc (along with a lot of other important info on using PHP on Heroku) is in the Getting Started on Heroku with PHP tutorial provided by Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#define-config-vars

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Config vars on heroku manifest themselves as environment variables, so you should be able to access them from php like you would any other environment variable, eg. using `getenv`.

First, set the variable from your console:

```
heroku config:set MY_VAR=somevalue
```

Then, access it from your code:

```
$my_env_var = getenv('MY_VAR');
```

Comment: You can see all vars on cmd with `heroku config` and get a specific with `heroku config:get <name>`

Comment: The Heroku vars are not available locally. but only on Heroku because they are Heroku config vars. With `heroku config` you do like an api call to the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

#### Another solution without `getenv()`

While the top rated answer answers the question, I want to add a solution that works both remote and local with the **Php Dotenv** Package:

1.Grab the variables you need with `heroku config -a <app>`, here the `mysql` string:

`CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL: mysql://<user>:<password>@<host>/<db>?reconnect=true`

2.Prepare your app locally

```
composer.json

{
"require": {
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.4"
    }
}


.env
host_heroku= ''
```

the index

```
index.php
include "config.php";
// Db connection is built
```

the config

```
config.php
include realpath(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__ . '/../');
$dotenv->load();
$db_hostname = $_ENV['host_heroku'];
```

3.Commit and push to heroku