# Accessing config vars with PHP and Node.js in Heroku

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, heroku

I'd like to access some config vars in a PHP file on a Heroku web app.
The app runs (and starts) with Node.js and utilizes both Node.js and PHP buildpacks from Heroku.

### What I want to happen

I would like to be able to start the app with Node.js and access the environment variables in my PHP file.

### What actually happens

When I start the app with Node.js, the config vars are accessible through `process.env('SOME_KEY')` (in the js file), and when I don't use Node.js and start in PHP the variables are accessible through `getenv('SOME_KEY')`, but when I start in Node.js `getenv('SOME_KEY')` (in the PHP file) returns undefined (likewise with `$_ENV['SOME_KEY']`).

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain why it's not accessible in PHP, if there is a way to make it accessible through PHP, or a way to send the variables from Node.js to the PHP file. Thank you!

Comment: Really not working ? Look here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#define-config-vars and I think he get it work too -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592832/use-heroku-config-vars-with-php

Comment: @SimonFranzen I've looked at both, those only talk about starting the app in PHP. My procfile looks like this: `web: node index.js`, and when I start in node.js, the variables are accessible in node.js and not in PHP. If I start in PHP (make an index.php file) and change my procfile to `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 /` then the variables will work in PHP. I want the variables to be accessible in PHP after starting in node.js.

Comment: i am trying in php..`getenv('SOME_KEY')` shows empty only..i have to do anything in vendor or composer? @illiteratecoder