# Use Heroku config vars in PHP?

Tags: php, heroku, yii2

I am trying to get the heroku variable in PHP.I have been defined the variable in heroku.But the problem is I am not able to access those variable.

I have checked the variable in web and also console..The variable is there.But in PHP it shows empty.Anything need to be do in the composer or vendor?

[image]

[image]

In views file i tried like:

```
getenv('VIDEO');
```

But this is empty.Please help.

i already checked these links:

1. [Use Heroku config vars with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592832/use-heroku-config-vars-with-php)
2. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-php

Comment: Try using this var_dump(get_defined_vars()); it will dump out all the vars defined including environmental. See then whether video is actually set.

Comment: that will return heroku variable ?

Comment: that didn't return the heroku variable. i checked@Doug

Comment: that how i mentioned in the answer..i got to know we can not get the heroku variable in localhost..thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **`Procfile`** in `vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2`..If that file is there then that config var function works.

```
$config_var = getenv('CONFIG_VAR');
```

Sorry I was checking in localhost after clone from heroku.In localhost procfile file is not there.That is why that did not work.In heroku application that file exist.It works in heroku app.