# Pass SMTP Credentials to PHPMailer Configuration without exposing it publicly in heroku

Tags: php, github, heroku, smtp, phpmailer

I'm using the **phpmailer** library. To send an email I need to specify an smtp server, smtp user and smtp password. The problem is I'm using the cloud platform **Heroku** where I use a github repository to autodeploy to heroku, I don't want my smtp username and password to be public. Is there a way to solve this?

Below is the code snippet

```
  $mail = new PHPMailer(false); // Passing `true` enables exceptions

    //Server settings
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;//Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();//Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp host';//Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;//Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'user';//SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'password';//SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';//Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;//TCP port to connect to


    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('example@example.com','myapp');
    $mail->addAddress('hi@examle.com');//Add a recipient
    //$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');//Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('support@example.com','Contact');



    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);//Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'test';

    $mail->Body    = 'this is a test';


    $mail->send();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to not expose but to use it in your code, is by setting your SMTP username and password in environment variables

The procedure to set environment variables for your heroku app is documented in this link - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Once you have set your username and password in your environment variables you can access them using the below code

```
    $mail->isSMTP();//Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp host';//Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;//Enable SMTP authentication
    //Assuming SMTP_USERNAME is your environment variable which holds username
    $mail->Username = getenv('SMTP_USERNAME');
    //Assuming SMTP_PASSWORD is your environment variable which holds password
    $mail->Password = getenv('SMTP_PASSWORD');
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';//Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;//TCP port to connect to
```

References
 - [Use Heroku config vars with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592832/use-heroku-config-vars-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible ways-

1. Use Heroku CLI 
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/command-line
2. You can create an admin page in you website from where you put smtp
   serve details that will persist to a file. This file will be
   available until the heroku dyno restart.
3. You can use **dropbox** for deployment
4. Instead of **Github** you can use **bitbucket** which
   is also free with git repo 
   https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-to-heroku-872013667.html